# BSOD kernel_security_check_failure - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, crash, bsod

I started getting kernel_security_check_failure BSOD every time I turn on my computer and letting it run. I managed to get a log text and a dump file. I checked on different sites and tried many solutions: running sfc scannow, defragging, memory error check, hard drive error check but it still happens. I read that the problem may be some drivers I had before the update. I had W7 -> W8 -> W7 -> W10. Between the OS changes I started from zero, meaning no programs or drivers installed from the old version, except for W7 to W10. Any ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Here are the files i managed to get from my last BSOD crash. The PC turns on and then crashes with the BSOD. I managed to get the files after rebooting the PC for a few times until it didn't crash.[here are the files I got](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3AvaKzQWiadY3NTT3dyT3FKWjQ)

Comment: When the PC has a BSOD again, note the first parameter and update your post with it

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Next time I'm going to turn on the PC I will update the question.

Comment: Your google drive link is broken. At least make the file(s) public if you want us to look at them. Better to [edit] the quesion and put the requested information **in the question**.

Comment: The link is not working

Comment: I can not use BlueScreenView because the PC crashes as soon as it finished loading it's files and before loading them the PC is not responding.

Comment: Changed the accessing settings in Google Drive. It should work now.

Comment: can you try different RAM? I have no idea how good the "Goodram DIMM 2GB, DDR3-1600, CL11 (GR1600D364L11/2G)" modules are. Also the RAM runs at 1360MHz instead 1333MHz and the CPU is a bit overclocked at 3570MHz instead of 3.5GHz. So also try to load the default BIOS/UEFI settings.

Comment: My MOBO is Asus Z97-K which is running in Performance Mode. The CPU is usually running at 4.5 Ghz. I was able to use it at even 4.6 Ghz. I will set the setting to normal and see if it will work.

Comment: ok, do this and report back if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I changed the settings to default and the PC crashed a few minutes after it loaded up the files. With OC-ing enabled it crashed way faster.

Comment: I can not change the RAM. I don't have other RAM modules to use.

Comment: can you ask a friend or relative if his RAM is compatible and try this RAM? If this works fine, your RAM is faulty. if his working RAM also causes issues, your OC damaged the motherboard

Comment: None of my friends have RAM that would support my MOBO. I think the only option left is to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter safe mode with cmd and then type `C:`, press enter, then type `BCDEDIT /SET {DEFAULT} BOOTMENUPOLICY LEGACY`
It didn't give me BSOD after that.

Comment: this displays the old text mode boot manager and not the graphical one. Interesting that this fixed your issue.

Comment: So that command actually didn't have anything to do with the BSOD

Comment: Anyway there is no official answer from Microsoft as to how to fix it. I jus tried different things and this command seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: ok, report back in a few days if the PC is still stable

Comment: After a week or so the PC still didn't crash with BSOD. I played a lot of games on it and I OC-d it and still didn't crash.

Comment: this is confusing. but if it works, be happy.